# Using Gtest is possible to return value of invoked function

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

Is it possible to return value which will be got after calling invoke?
For example,

```
int foo(int a, int b) {return a+b;}

class FooMock {
  MOCK_METHOD0(MockMethod, int(int a, int b));
}

void bar()
{
  FooMock mock;
  EXPECT_CALL(mock,MockMethod(_,_)).WillRepeatedly(DoAll(Invoke(foo),Return(result_of_foo)));
//Firstly foo should be invoked, secondly, result of function should be returned as result of MockMethod
}
```

How make result_of_foo be equal to result of function foo?
Or does exist another way to return the calculated value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's simpler than you think. If you `Invoke` a function, the returned value will be what your function returns.

```
EXPECT_CALL(mock,MockMethod(_,_)).WillRepeatedly(Invoke(foo));
```